# Generate numbers in range depending on variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, algorithm

I'm looking for a way to do the following as clean as possible.

I have 2 values and I would like to generate x amount of numbers that are in between those 2 values depending on how many the user would like.

Let's say I have 2 numbers: 10 and 50.
Now I would like to generate 19 numbers (variable input) in this range equally spread.
So my wanted outcome would be [12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48]
If the user would like 6 numbers it would be [16,22,28,34,40,46]
If the user would like 9 numbers it would be [14,18,22,26,30,34,38,42,46]

And so on... so ideally my code would look like this

```
function getNumbersInRange(low, high, amountOfNumbers) {
//low is 10
//high is 50
//amountOfNumbers is 9 

//something something...

  return [14,18,22,26,30,34,38,42,46]
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Divide the difference between the top and bottom by the amount of numbers, to get the difference between each number. Round this down to an integer.

Comment: Please always provide an [mcve] and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to find increment, which is `(high - low) / number` and use it to calculate each number

```js
function getNumbersInRange(low, high, amountOfNumbers) {
  let r = [];
  let add = parseInt((high - low) / amountOfNumbers);
  if (add > 0) {
    for (let i=1; i<=amountOfNumbers; i++) {
      r.push(low + add * i);
    }
  }
  return r;
} 

console.log(getNumbersInRange(10, 50, 9));
```